# How to find height of sidebar in checkout page using js

Tags: javascript, magento, magento2, checkout, sidebar

How can we get height of sidebar in checkout using js
[image]

Is there any way to get the sidebar height?

Answer (score 0):

first grab the element

```
const myEl = document.querySelector("#whatever-your-sidebar-id-is");
```

then you can either check the height with `clientHeight` or `getBoundingClientRect().height` :

```
myEl.getBoundingClientRect().height
```

Comment: i have check this
 $( document ).ajaxStop(function() {
        var sidebarHeight = $('#opc-sidebar').outerHeight();
        console.log(sidebarHeight);
but on inital load its works fine.after taht reload the same page shows different values

Answer (score 0):

You can get the height with offsetHeight and offsetWidth properties of the element.

```
elem = document.querySelector('#sidebar-id-or-class')

elem = document.querySelector('.cart-summary')
```

then check the height with **offsetHeight**

```
console.log(elem.offsetHeight)
```

The function will give you relatively with properties of the DOM element to get its the width and height.

Comment: i tried this also but not working.
Can i get a working code example